# Is this XSLT inefficient?

Tags: optimization, xslt

I have got an answer from [my last question about translating an XML file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8274068/) and it inspired me to play with it. I came up with a different solution, but I have the feeling that the two last selects are suboptimal. Can this be done in a nicer way or more efficient?

The stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:param name="pFrom" select="'en'"/>
  <xsl:param name="pTo" select="'de'"/>


  <xsl:variable name="translations" select="document('translations.xml')"/>

  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@name">
    <xsl:variable name="thisname" select="." />

    <xsl:variable name="entry" select="$translations/translations/entry[attribute::node()[name()=$pFrom and $thisname=.]]"></xsl:variable>
    <xsl:attribute name="name" select="$entry/attribute::node()[local-name() = $pTo]"></xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The source:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<grammar>
  <element name="table" />
  <element name="chair" />
</grammar>
```

And the translation file (`translations.xml`):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<translations>
    <entry en="table" de="Tisch" fr="Table" />
    <entry en="chair" de="Stuhl" fr="Chaise"/>
</translations>
```

The result is:

```
<grammar>
   <element name="Tisch"/>
   <element name="Stuhl"/>
</grammar>
```

An example: when I go from 'en' to 'de' and I am at the first `name` attribute ('table') in the source file, I look into the translations file for en entry where en="table" and select the 'de' attribute for the name.

Comment: @_Patrick: "Efficiency" can be something very different in different cases. For example, using keys won't help (or may even slow down) the execution in case when only a single search is made. There isn't an XSLT facility to build an `xsl:key` index and keep it cached between different invocations of the same transformation. This means that every time the transformation is invoked, the index will need to be built again. Keep this consideration in mind when designing your XSLT applications.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use keys:

```
<xsl:key name="en" match="translations/entry" use="@en"/>
<xsl:key name="de" match="translations/entry" use="@de"/>
<xsl:key name="fr" match="translations/entry" use="@fr"/>
```

and then

```
  <xsl:template match="@name">
    <xsl:attribute name="name" select="key($pFrom, current(), $translatations)/@*[local-name() = $pTo]"/>
  </xsl:template>
```

(I assume you use XSLT 2.0).

Comment: I still have to learn a lot. Thanks for the clean answer, which works perfectly!